# group by with 2 conditions total and expiry count in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need the total and expiry date group by taluk name and taluk_code. kindly help me to group by taluk name and taluk_code.
With Total and Expiry Date:

```
SELECT
    l.taluk_code, t.taluk_name,
    count (serial_number) as Total
FROM
    license_register l, taluk t where l.taluk_code=t.taluk_code and rev_district_code='17' and 
    l.validity_to <= now()
  group by l.taluk_code, t.taluk_name
```

without Expiry date

```
 SELECT
    l.taluk_code, t.taluk_name,
    count (serial_number) as Total
FROM
    license_register l, taluk t where l.taluk_code=t.taluk_code and rev_district_code='17' 
  group by l.taluk_code, t.taluk_name
```

kindly combine and give the solution

```
"taluk_code"    "taluk_name"    "total"
"01 "   "Ariyalur"  2
"04 "   "Sendurai"  1


"taluk_code"    "taluk_name"    "ExpiryCount"
"01 "   "Ariyalur"  2
"04 "   "Sendurai"  1
```

I need the below output:

```
"taluk_code"    "taluk_name"    "total" "ExpiryCount"
"01 "   "Ariyalur"  2 1
"04 "   "sendurai"  1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    l.taluk_code,
    t.taluk_name,
    count(serial_number) AS total,
    count(serial_number) FILTER (WHERE l.validity_to <= now()) AS expiry_count
FROM
    license_register l,
    taluk t
WHERE
    l.taluk_code = t.taluk_code
    AND rev_district_code = '17'
GROUP BY
    l.taluk_code,
    t.taluk_name;
```

filter tutorial: https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter#footnote-0